# Why injectJavaScript in React Native WebView always need setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I'm at the learning phase of react-native and was testing the sample code provided in the React Native WebView documentation.

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const run = `
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      true;
    `;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.webref.injectJavaScript(run);
    }, 3000);

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView
          ref={r => (this.webref = r)}
          source={{ uri: 'https://logrocket.com/' }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If I'm not wrapping `this.webref.injectJavaScript(run);` in `setTimeout()` method, the javascript doesn't execute

Question is how do I identify whether the page has done with loading so that javascript can be executed safely right after the page load finish (without wrapping in `setTimeout`).

P. S -
My requirement is to display a button on the page, once the page has finished rendering.

Perhaps`useEffect` helps?

Comment: did u manage to figure this out ? we are also blocked on this

Comment: unfortunately no.

Comment: @Sandeep - try `useEffect`